# how to push into an array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add into an array. I don't know how to traverse and add objects correctly.

*I have data array：*

```
const data = [
  {
    1: "Apple", 
    2: "Xiaomi"
   }
];

const list = [];

data.forEach(function(key, value) {
    console.log("key", key);
})

console.log(list)
```

**I want this effect to be as follows：**

```
list: [{
 {
  value: 1,
  title: 'Apple'
 },
 {
  value: 2,
  title: 'Xiaomi'
 }
}]
```

Comment: Your desired result is invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and make the assumption that `data` is an object of key/value pairs and you want to transform it to an array of objects.

```
// Assuming you have an object with key/value pairs.
const data = {
  1: "Apple",
  2: "Xiaomi"
};

// Convert the data object into an array by iterating over data's keys.
const list = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  return {
    value: key,
    title: data[key]
  }
});

console.log(list)
```

Output:

```
[ 
  { 
    value: '1', 
    title: 'Apple' 
  },
  { 
    value: '2', 
    title: 'Xiaomi' 
  } 
]
```

If you actually need `value` to be numbers instead of strings, you can do it this way:

```
const list = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  return {
    value: Number(key),
    title: data[key]
  }
});
```

And if you are OK with using a more modern version of JavaScript (ECMAScript 2017) this works nicely:

```
const data = {
  1: "Apple",
  2: "Xiaomi"
};

// Using Object.entries gives you the key and value together.
const list = Object.entries(data).map(([value, title]) => {
  return { value, title }
});
```

Comment: Hopefully, it was my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660082/11299053) to inspire `Object.entries()` solution (now it is worth an upvote from my end), because your initial solution would require unnecessary lookups to initial object which makes it not simply *less modern*, but **slower** at larger lists, especially.

Answer (score 5):

Your expected output is invalid. You can first retrieve all the values from the object with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to form the array in the structure you want.

Try the following way:

```js
const data = [
  {
    1: "Apple", 
    2: "Xiaomi"
   }
];
const list = Object.values(data[0]).map((el,i) => ({value: i+1, title: el})) ;
console.log(list);
```

You can use the existing *key* of the object with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like the following way:

```js
const data = [
  {
    1: "Apple", 
    2: "Xiaomi"
   }
];
const list = Object.entries(data[0]).map(item => ({value: item[0], title: item[1]}));
console.log(list);
```

Comment: While this one is getting upvoted it implicitly assumes that keys are *autoincremented* numbers which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg, I have added another answer which uses the current key of the the object. Thanks for helping me to improve the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
const data = ['Apple', 'Xiaomi'];

const result = data.map((item, index) => ({value: index, title: item}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one implicitly assumes that keys are autoincremented numbers which is not necessarily true

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to turn key names into values and those are not necessarily autoincremented numbers you might want to look at [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const data = {1: "Apple", 2: "Xiaomi"};

const res = Object.entries(data).map(entry => ({value: entry[0], title: entry[1]}));

console.log(res);
```